# Некорректно отрабатывает запись в $_SESSION

Tags: php, сессия

Добрый день!
Заметил, что некорректно стала отрабатывать запись в сессию.
В таком случае:

```
if(!empty($_POST['option'])) {
if (isset($_SESSION['option'])) {
$_SESSION['option'] = $_POST['option'];
}}
```

Срабатывает, и пишет в сессию.

А в таком случае:

```
if(!empty($_POST['option'])) {
$_SESSION['option'] = $_POST['option'];
}
```

Запись срабатывает не корректно.
При том что, в том же файле, `$_SESSION['option']` - вызывается, а в другом файле - уже не видно в сессии такого значения.

`session_start();` везде проставлен корректно.

Подскажите, чем может быть вызвано такое поведение?

P.S. При чем пишет в сессию в первом случае, даже если до этого $_SESSION['option'] не было представлено.

**UPD**
*В целом решил проблему добавлением костылей:
Из формы от куда берутся `$_POST['option']` сначала уходит на доп.файл, там пишет в сессию и возвращает в нужное место `header('location: ...')`*

Comment: А в чем некорректность то?

Comment: @rjhdby Не записывает в сессию - нельзя получить на других страницах.

Comment: 99.99%, что вы просто чего то не договариваете и на самом деле эксперимент не был чистым. Т.е. где-то что-то еще поменяли и посчитали это неважным. Представленный код абсолютно корректный и рабочий.

Comment: Вероятно, но при этом я сам не могу понять что не договариваю))
В целом ситуация выглядит так:
На первой странице у нас есть форма, в которой пользователь указывает место и даты. От туда это все передается на вторую страницу, и по введенным параметрам ищет совпадения. На этой же второй странице - назовем её список товаров - происходит запись в сессию данных упавших через `$_POST`. Но при клике на определенный товар, на его страницу запись из сессий не передается. А на странице товара, в доп-фильтре, можно заново указать даты, и от туда - пишутся данные в сессию.

Comment: UPD. Если пытаюсь использовать рабочий код в тех местах, где стоял не работавший - все равно в сессию не пишет. Вероятно что-то не так с файлом? Вроде бы UTF без бом

Comment: Для начала посмотрите, что возвращает сервер в ответ на запрос. Заголовки и тело. Вполне возможно, что увиденный там "fatal error" сразу укажет, где проблема. Если нет, то расставляете повсюду var_dump'ы и начинаете долгую и печальную отладку